# Kill looping audio track?

Tags: linux, firefox, audio, kill

My Firefox crashed leaving part of an audio track stuck in a loop. How can I kill this audio process without logging out? (I don't know what process to kill)

OS: Linux - Fedora

Apparently the following command should restart the sound server /etc/init.d/alsasound restart but I don't have an alsasound script. I have also been told that nasd is the script to run but I don't have that either.

**EDIT:**

Alas, I couldn't hold out any longer. I rebooted my system and now all is fine. It wasn't until the final kill all processes that the sound actually stopped so I guess I don't have a service script to stop/start my sound.

Comment: You might try `kill -9 $(pgrep firefox)` (I've'nt used FF in a while - the process name may be different

Comment: @new123456 Thanks for that, it was the first thing I tried but this sound process doesn't have Firefox in its name. BTW, I think killall firefox will do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look what processes using the sound device and then kill them. To find out what uses sound run:

fuser -v /dev/snd/*

Comment: Even though I cannot test this on the actual problem I had. I think this would have worked so I'm accepting it as the answer.